# "If, Then" Statement - registering back-to-back mouse clicks

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my program to register three consecutive mouse clicks.  Upon each mouse click, a unique object is drawn (pre-determined location and shape).  The first click = first object appears, if they click again = second object appears, and if they click a third time = third object appears.  What should this look like?

Here's what I have, which isn't working:

```
def printer(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print(x,y)

    if event.x in range (130,224) and event.y in range(197,305):
        canvas.create_oval(146, 158, 140, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)

    elif event.x in range (130,224) and event.y in range(197,305):
        canvas.create_oval(180.5, 158, 174.5, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)

    elif event.x in range (130,224) and event.y in range(197,305):
        canvas.create_oval(209, 158, 215, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)
```

Comment: The "then" in "if…then…else" statements as they are use in *other* programming languages does not mean "later". But to your code: If you have an `if` and an `elif` with the same condition, the `elif` will not be executed. `elif` is executed if the `if` fails only. To solve your problem you have to keep a state. That would be a variable which changes with every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to maintain a variable counting how often the user has already clicked, and then, depending on the current value of that variable, draw the figure in the one place or in the other.

```
counter = 0

def printer(event):
    global counter
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    if event.x in range (130,224) and event.y in range(197,305):
        if counter == 0:
            canvas.create_oval(146, 158, 140, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)
        elif counter == 1:
            canvas.create_oval(180.5, 158, 174.5, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)
        elif counter == 2:
            canvas.create_oval(209, 158, 215, 164, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)
        counter += 1
```

Also, there's quite a bit of repetition in your code. Since the coordinates where to draw seem to be the only thing that changes, you could use a dictionary (or a simple array) to store where to draw the figure on what click count. Also, using `range` to check whether a number is in a certain range is wasteful, as you not only create a new list every time, but then check *every value* in that list. Instead, just use `<=` and `<`.

```
coords = {0: (146, 158, 140, 164), 
          1: (180.5, 158, 174.5, 164), 
          2: (209, 158, 215, 164)}
counter = 0

def printer(event):
    global counter
    if 130 <= event.x < 224 and 197 <= event.y < 305:
        if counter in coords:
            a, b, c, d = coords[counter]
            canvas.create_oval(a, b, c, d, outline="indianred2", fill="red", width=1.5)
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has support for double and triple clicks out of the box. For example:

```
canvas.bind("<1>", self.on_click)
canvas.bind("<Double-1>", self.on_double)
canvas.bind("<Triple-1>", self.on_triple)
```

If you want the user to be able to click very slow, you'll have to count the clicks yourself.